# Guppy color change problem with if/else. how to solve it?

Tags: colors, pine-script

I have a guppy strategy which should enter either long (when guppy becomes green under certain conditions) or short (when guppy becomes red under certain conditions). To determine the colour in pine script I used if/else. What the problem is? I'm getting the third type of colour when none of two conditions are met (let's say grey colour) and in the situation where, for example, i get red1=>grey=>red2 My strategy sends signal to close previous trade when red2 occurs and open new one with the same direction. In my strategy grey is not a signal for entering/exiting the position, so i want to make the current 'grey' to be coloured the same way the previous segment was colored until fully opposite condition was met. I tried else na, but those intermediate condition still gives me wrong signals, i also tried to put plotcolor=plotcolor[1] in 'else' but this type of command cannot be placed in pine script. Can please anyone help me to solve this?

```
plot_color0 = if hma8>hma0[2] and hma7>hma0[2] and hma6>hma0[2] and hma5>hma0[2] and hma4>hma0[2] and hma3>hma0[2] and hma2>hma0[2] and hma1>hma0[2] 
      aqua
  else 
      if hma8<hma0[2] and hma7<hma0[2] and hma6<hma0[2] and hma5<hma0[2] 
      and hma4<hma0[2] and hma3<hma0[2] and hma2<hma0[2] and hma1<hma0[2]
          maroon 
      else 
          gray

    longCondition = (plot_color0 != plot_color0[1]) and (plot_color0 == aqua) shortCondition = (plot_color0 != plot_color0[1]) and (plot_color0 == maroon)
```

basically the problem happens when tradingview.com/x/AnFOTdEa colour turns blue (long signal which gives me command to close previous positions and to open new) after that turns grey and again blue and once again i get long signal (which closes my previous long position and opens it once again). What i want to figure out is how to set alert which either would not trigger after grey colour if previous trade signal direction was the same direction to previous signal or to remove this 'else gray' in the way, where the colour will change only if opposite direction conditions was met

if i put plot0 != gray in conditions alert simply doesn't trigger at all obviously, and i can't exclude 'else gray'

in the end i want alert to trigger only if previous trigger was in opposite direction besides longCondition and shortCondition mentioned above

Comment: Please add your current code and output, showing what failed.

Comment: Edit your question. Insert the script code into the body of the question and format it with the keys `CTRL+K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the condition in this form, the gray color will remain only on the first few bars.

```
plot_color0 = gray
plot_color0 := if hma8>hma0[2] and hma7>hma0[2] and hma6>hma0[2] and hma5>hma0[2] and hma4>hma0[2] and hma3>hma0[2] and hma2>hma0[2] and hma1>hma0[2] 
      aqua
  else 
      if hma8<hma0[2] and hma7<hma0[2] and hma6<hma0[2] and hma5<hma0[2] 
      and hma4<hma0[2] and hma3<hma0[2] and hma2<hma0[2] and hma1<hma0[2]
          maroon 
      else 
          plot_color0[1]
```